# PHP | Add data to database, update if exists

Tags: php, pdo

I have the code done, but for some reason it doesn't update the data. It just adds it again.

Here is the code:

```
$update = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `steamid`) VALUES (:name, :steamid) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), steamid=VALUES(steamid)");

$update->bindParam(':name', $userJSON['response']['players']['0']['personaname']);  
$update->bindParam(':steamid', $steamid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```

Comment: Ok so if you have the same name and steamid what would you like to update? i can't get that from your code

Comment: I would like to update/check the steamid and name basically.

Comment: If they are alerady identical, there is no need to update them, you could just use INSERT IGNORE, it's the same syntax as INSERT just add the IGNORE word. This statement will insert if it can, and if not will not throw any errors. Also you should add an unique composite key on name and steamid

Comment: The name could change anytime though.

Comment: steamid is a unique key?

Comment: That value what I would like to update I would have to set to unique key?

Comment: why not use UPDATE statment?